# how to reload VideoDisplay?

Tags: apache-flex, videodisplay

I want to play a flv video from a web server, but this video may be updated after several minutes on the web server. So how could I reload this video every minute in case video is updated?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

just saw this thread on the ADOBE forum site as well! 
I'm not quiet sure where the problem lies? as I have just checked it on my one and it looks to me just reinstate & address this with an Init call through a Timer!
My set up is using my .flv video in a Pop-up type so I do ReLoad on request from the module! but it also has everything included  as PAUSE & START within the window etc.

So what is it you need to achieve in more detail? regards aktell

Comment: Hi, assume the video from an url (example.com) will change every 30 seconds, so I want to reload the video every 30 seconds